# Read Magic Mouse and Apple Wireless Keyboard Battery percentage

Tags: macos, power-management

I want to ask you If anybody know a simple way to access Mouse and Keyboard battery state in Mac OS. There are some API to access this information? Thanks!

Comment: I think you maybe want to post this on the Stack Exchange site Superuser.
Unless you want your application or program to check this?
http://superuser.com

Comment: No

I'm developer I want to write a little app that needs the Mouse and Keyboard battery state. I've searched but I don' t find anything on the web!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Keyboard it is:

```
ioreg -n "IOAppleBluetoothHIDDriver" | grep -i "batterypercent" | sed 's/[^[:digit:]]//g'
```

and for the Magic Mouse it is:

```
ioreg -n "BNBMouseDevice" | grep -i "batterypercent" | sed 's/[^[:digit:]]//g'
```