# Display Magic Keyboard and Magic Mouse Battery in Touch bar using BetterTouchTool

Tags: applescript

Based on this question: [Display Magic Mouse Battery in Touch bar using BetterTouchTool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50190787/display-magic-mouse-battery-in-touch-bar-using-bettertouchtool)

I'm using this BetterTouchToll for make my touch bar more interesting.

He accept some Apple Scripts for more dynamic, so I start to study this scripts.

Now I wanna to display my Magic Mouse and **Magic Keyboard** Battery  on my touch bar, for this I was trying this code, but is not working.

```
set finalDevice to do shell script "ioreg -c AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService | grep '\"Product\" =' | tail -2"

if finalDevice contains "Magic Keyboard" then
    if finalDevice contains "Magic Mouse" then
        set remaining to do shell script "ioreg -c AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService | grep BatteryPercent | tail -2 | sed 's/[^[:digit:]]//g'"
        "⌨️ " & remaining & "%" & "️" & remaining & "%"
    else
        set remaining to do shell script "ioreg -c AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService | grep BatteryPercent | tail -1 | sed 's/[^[:digit:]]//g'"
        "⌨️ " & remaining & "%"
    end if
else if finalDevice contains "Magic Mouse" then
    set remaining to do shell script "ioreg -c AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService | grep BatteryPercent | tail -1 | sed 's/[^[:digit:]]//g'"
    "️" & remaining & "%"
else
    "nothing"
end if
```

**The problems**:

- When I get the `remaining` with both devices it comes "one battery level" + jump line + "other battery level".

My answer should be: `"⌨️ 45%️39%"`

And now is:

```
"⌨️ 39
45%️39
45%"
```

- On the `finalDevice` the Mouse or the Keyboard could be the last one. So I would need to check it position somehow;

This would not be ok: `"⌨️ 39%️45%"`

Comment: Depending how often you run it and how powerful your computer is, this script will drain your system resources like a bitch.

Comment: @CJK Thanks for the inside, but is not the question. Anyway BTT has a time set for when I wanna do it. My case is 30min.

Comment: I know that’s not the question,  That’s why I didn’t leave it as an answer, but rather as a comment.  Obvs.  But, you really ought to consider rewriting that script.  Or refactor is at least.  If you really need to do a shell script command, you can do it once, then use AppleScript to get the different bits of the information you need, which looks like it’d be an easy thing to do since the `grep` and `sed` commands are simple ones.

Comment: `grep` and `sed` look more simple for me, but I'm open to suggestions. Just cannot see how rewrite or refactor would be good in this case. @CJK